# Column 'SHAPE' cannot be null in mysql database even if the query string is correct

Tags: sql, php, mysql-spatial

I am trying to write an POLYGON into an column named SHAPE which is a geometry type. And created query which looks

```js
$sql = "INSERT INTO rokka(zone,district,location,area,SHAPE) 
VALUES ('$zone','$district','$location','$area',PolygonFromText('$polywrite'))";
```

The variable `$polywrite` comes as

```js
var polygon = 'Polygon((' + northeastlngLat[0] + ' ' + northeastlngLat[1] + ',' + northwestlngLat[0] + ' ' + northwestlngLat[1] + ',' + southwestlngLat[0] + ' ' + southwestlngLat[1] + ',' + southeastlngLat[0] + ' ' + southeastlngLat[1] + ',' + northeastlngLat[0] + ' ' + northeastlngLat[1] + '))';
$polywrite = "<script>document.write(polygon)</script>";
```

The arrays contain the coordinates.
And when executing

```js
if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    session_start();
    header('location: admin.html');
    session_destroy();
} else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
    }
```

The error it shows is

```
Column 'SHAPE' cannot be nullError: INSERT INTO rokka(zone, district,location,area,SHAPE) VALUES ('Rapti', 'Rolpa','Liwang','603750', PolygonFromText('Polygon((85.06290725100276 28.00935569163021,85.06392404943365 28.0093478254886,85.06393735099435 28.01070145242192,85.06292053985693 28.010709319009717,85.06290725100276 28.00935569163021))'))
Column 'SHAPE' cannot be null
```

But whenever I run the query

```js
INSERT INTO rokka(zone, district,location,area,SHAPE)
VALUES ('Rapti', 'Rolpa','Liwang','603750', PolygonFromText('Polygon((85.06290725100276 28.00935569163021,85.06392404943365 28.0093478254886,85.06393735099435 28.01070145242192,85.06292053985693 28.010709319009717,85.06290725100276 28.00935569163021))'))
```

in my database directly It works exactly as it should. All the values are written into the respective columns. Please help me figure out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure in line `$polywrite = "<script>document.write(polygon)</script>";` It looks like, you generate a part of html document and writes polygon via javascript. Why not to use `polygon` directly in `$sql = ... `?

Comment: The columns specified in `INSERT` statement in the error message do not match the columns in the statement you said you assigned to `$sql`. Is it being changed somewhere?

Comment: dimitry.v.kiselev in the  `polygon` the coordinates are to be transfromed that i do using proj4js (javascript library), hence need to get the value from   javascript part of page.

Comment: @EvilGenius the query has been edited. Mistakenly I had posted different query and results.

Comment: why not to use proj4php?

Comment: Can you point me official documentation to proj4php? I found many libraries, but want to create new utm projection system 3 degree zoned and with Everest 1830 datum. So I want library where i can create custom utm system.

Comment: May be a case-sensitivity issue, you can try uppercase POLYGON here: `PolygonFromText('POLYGON` -- Or! Perhaps `PolygonFromText` is failing to resolve in the PHP query and you need to pre-build the geometry in an earlier statement before inserting.

Comment: Here is a link to proj4php recomended by proj4 github wiki http://sourceforge.net/projects/proj4php/ and here is a proj4php wiki http://sourceforge.net/p/proj4php/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line `$polywrite = "<script>document.write(polygon)</script>"` you are trying to use javascript code while it is imposible in php side. All php scripts run before javascript.
You can use [proj4php](http://sourceforge.net/p/proj4php/wiki/Home/) as mentioned in the comments.
Another solution is to fill the `polywrite` variable at javascript side and create an Ajax request sending `polywrite' to a php page.

### javascript side:

```
var polygon = 'Polygon((' + northeastlngLat[0] + ' ' + northeastlngLat[1] + ',' + northwestlngLat[0] + ' ' + northwestlngLat[1] + ',' + southwestlngLat[0] + ' ' + southwestlngLat[1] + ',' + southeastlngLat[0] + ' ' + southeastlngLat[1] + ',' + northeastlngLat[0] + ' ' + northeastlngLat[1] + '))';
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  data: { 
    "polywrite": polygon
  },
}).done(function() {
   // do something when done
});
```

### php page:

```
$polywrite = $_GET['polywrite']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO rokka(zone,district,location,area,SHAPE) 
   VALUES('$zone','$district','$location','$area',PolygonFromText('$polywrite'))";
...
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems you try to persist your entity and its id remains null. That's why your get a constraint violation error.

- To simply solve this error I suggest you to try create your database table using auto-incrementation option on your SHAPE field. It should solve your problem, I guess.

  OR
- Reading the documentation on [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) I would suggest that the value is only updated after the last trigger runs. I also created a trigger which inserts the result of LAST_INSERT_ID() into another table and it would always insert the id of the row inserted by the INSERT statement before or 0 if there was no previous INSERT.

From within an insert or update trigger you can always refer to the state after the statement by using NEW.column where column is a column-name of your table. [See the documentation for examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: @Samane The id is already an auto increment field.

Comment: @poshan OK, did you check the second case?

Comment: In bande khoda che gonahi karde , hey ru soalesh comment mizarim fek mikone javabi chizi umade. خخخخخ                malume taze-varedi. inja ziad be ye nafar emtiaz bedi stackoverflow mifahme emtiaz manfi mide

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85491/persian-2